# Unable to trace decrease in Reputation

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

My reputation drastically drowned from 140 to 28. I don't know why. There should be some trace why, when and by whom. I checked the reputation tab. But it does not show any such drowning.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you guys... i will keep in mind before posting my answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to [How do I filter a generic list in .Net2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179514/how-do-i-filter-a-generic-list-in-net2-0/3179548#3179548) was locked and deleted by the Community user 2 days ago.  That's a clear sign that it was voted "spam or offensive" enough times to have it removed, which costs you 100 reputation.  <strike>The other -12 probably came from downvotes on that and other answers.</strike>  As [@Ether](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132636/ether) pointed out in a comment, the additional -12 comes from the -2 that's applied for each individual spam flag.

Comment: Actually by mistake I put link of sorting generic list instead of filtering. When I realized after a -ve repo, then I changed to correct link. But they downvoted me. and said answer should be on the same site not other. I dont think , all user posts solution to the questions. Most the guy supplies link too if they found useful and its not a matter of flag or spam

Comment: What should i do to gain my repo back. as its not my fault.

Comment: @Amit: try to forget about it and move on.  It looks like you were a bit of a victim of a bandwagon attack - one person downvoted your answer and flagged as spam because it was just a link. It looks like spam unless you visit the link, so other 10k rep users would have seen this flag in the tools and followed suit without actually checking the link. In the future, try to be more descriptive when posting links in answers, write a short paragraph summarizing the linked page and why you think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: @Amit: I'd follow @Andy E's head's advice about being more descriptive and not posting simple links.  Since the answer wasn't spam (you weren't linking to your own blog) or offensive, I'll try to refund the rep.  It may take a couple of days for it to show back up.

Comment: @Amit: Actually, that rep is back already.  I'm just going to delete that answer so it doesn't happen again.  Please leave a new answer with a summary along with the link.

Comment: 6 spam/offensive flags adds up to a total penalty of -112: -2 * 6 for the votes themselves, plus a -100 penalty after the sixth flag.

Comment: @Ether: Oh, that's right.  I forgot that the -2 was applied for each individual spam flag.

Answer (score 4):

Check at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

You can check which answer/question cause your rep drop, but votes are anonymous, you will not see by whom

Comment: If a question has been deleted then that won't appear on the report so you'll be none the wiser.

Comment: @ChrisF: if that were the case it wouldn't appear on the site either, until a recalc was done.

Comment: @ChrisF, IIRC, I saw some users reported they can check flagged posts with -100.

Comment: @Andy - of course it wouldn't, silly me. Unless a recalc had been done due to suspicious voting activity.